# Unable to clone Git project in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am under a proxy network and i have tried cloning a public git repo to jenkins. But i am facing **Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin ls-remote -h** git@hostname:username/project.git HEAD.

I have even set up the path of git installations as : C:\Program Files\Git\bin and name as Default in git installations under Jenkins configure settings.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` should be `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`. Try to find out where you can configure it.

Comment: Sad part is that, i have tried even that.. but i landed with no luck.

Comment: Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h git@hostname:username/project.git HEAD

Comment: `hostname:username` is a bit odd. To my knowledge, `username` should be a port instead.

Comment: Do you configure your ssh certification - Add your public key into your profile settings? Try to use the http url instead of the ssh: `git ls-remote -h http://<username>:<password>@<hostname>/<project.git>`

Answer (score 2):

Please find your git.exe file in your local( for me it's C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe) and set this  under Git Path of Jenkin's Global Tool Configuration. This would solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:
1. Ensure you can run this git command successfully in the server where Jenkins is running: git.exe ls-remote -h git@hostname:username/project.git. It's to ensure git, network connetion and your account is working 
2. Congiure the repo in Jenkins SCM/GIT portion, in fact Jenkins will do validation and check against your configuration and return failure once the repo is indicated

Normally, it's not recommended to use hostname:username here, just use the plain url if it's a public repo, or use SSH key for a private repo (SSK key can be configured in Jenkins Global Credentials section.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your SSH configuration in GitLab / GitHub, do you store the public key correctly. Just to insure the problem occures somewhere else, try to use the http url instead of the ssh: 
`git ls-remote -h http://<username>:<password>@<hostname>/<namespace>/<project.git>`

Note that the part behind the colon (git@hostname:username/project.git) is not necessarily your username, its the namespace of the project. Maybe you switched something there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. Following are the things which I have done to resolve the above issue: 1) I have unset the proxy settings in my local. 2) Saved the Username and password of my user in Jenkins, (In Windows, Under list of services -> Jenkins -> Properties -> Login), so that the repo will clone using my user in Jenkins. (By Default, Jenkins won't run with our user). and hence, since I have access to the git repo, and I have mentioned Jenkins to use my own username while cloning, the authentication got successful and I could able to clone the git repo in the Jenkins. :) –